# Is it possible to disable the RStudio connections pane?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I wonder if we can disable the RStudio Connection Pane altogether?

What I tried so far:

- untick Connection in Tools / Global Options / Pane Layout / upper right segment --> does not work as it automatically puts the tick on Connection in the lower right segment
- tried to find an environment variable and put it in Renviron.site --> did not find any

I am running RStudio Server 1.3.959 (Middlemist Red) for Ubuntu Bionic with R4.0.0 installed.

Comment: The global options method works for me, have you updated R studio recently?

Comment: Unticking in the pane layout works for me, I'm on RStudio 1.4.1103

Comment: Hi @McMahok and Ofek Shilon and thanks for the answers. In the newest version for RStudio Server (2021.09.1+372 (Ghost Orchid) for Ubuntu Bionic), I can confirm that unticking the Connection Pane actually gets rid of it. However, immediately after connecting to the database (via dbConnect() e.g.), the Connection Pane appears again and for a big database it take several seconds up to a minute to build up. 

So my question remains: is there a way to get rid of the Connection Pane for good so it does not reappear after connecting to a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works for me is setting `options(connectionObserver = NULL)` before starting the connection. I do this on a case by case basis, but you could set it on the `.rProfile` file for it to be a default.

Comment: Thanks @kurast ! This indeed solves my problem, such an easy fix! Also thank you for the suggestion with the `.rProfile` for creating a default, will consider it.